# Удаление из массива

Tags: java

Никак не могу понять этот алгоритм ,Может кто объяснит мне поэтапно... Буду благодарен

```
  searchKey=55;
        for(j=0;j<nElems;j++){ // Поиск удаляемого элемента 
            if(arr[j]==searchKey){
                break;
            }
        }

        for(int k = j;k<nElems-1;k++){   
         // Сдвиг последующих элементов 
             arr[k] = arr[k+1];
        }
           nElems--; // Уменьшение размера
```

Алгоритм реализован из книги

Comment: Бред тут происходит. Массив нужен когда данные статичны. Если они динамичные, то используйте `ArrayList`, который автоматом обновляет размеры и зачищает дыры при вставке, удалении и т.д

Comment: @Flippy четко однако )

Comment: Похоже на код портированный из Си

Comment: @Barmaley да это из книги для алгоритмов...)

Comment: Походу плохая книга, в Си надо делать по другому - на указателях, я на Java тоже совсем по другому

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- выше обьявлена переменная `j` в которой будет находиться индекс искомого элемента в массиве
- первый цикл пробегается по массиву при каждой итерации идет проверка значения на искомое, если это так, то выходим из цикла через `break`
- после этого цикла переменная `j` содержит индекс искомого значения в массиве
- далее второй цикл сдвигает элементы влево начиная с индекса `j`
- последний элемент массива становится "удаленным", на самом деле он есть, просто на него не будут обращать внимание циклы, так как переменная `nElrms` уменьшилась

Answer (score 1):

#### В двух словах

Данный кусок кода "вырезает" из входной последовательности первый элемент со значением `searchKey`

---

#### А теперь подробнее:

`searchKey` - искомое значение в последовательности
`for(j=0;j<nElems;j++)` - проходим по последовательности от `0`до `nElems` (скорее всего - это длина последовательности)
`if(arr[j]==searchKey) { break; }` - если j-й элемент последовательности `arr` равен `searchKey` (в данном случае 55), тогда `break` (прекращаем работу цикла, при этом `j` = индексу элемента со значением `searchkey`

```
for(int k = j;k<nElems-1;k++){   
         arr[k] = arr[k+1];
    }
```

Проходим по этой же последовательности, только теперь не от начала до конца, а от `j` до `nElems - 1` и текущему элементы последовательности присваиваем значение следующего (проще говоря, вырезаем элемент со значением `searchKey`)
`nElems--` - уменьшаем длину последовательности на единицу.

---

Но, если говорить откровенно, то абсолютно согласен с оратором в комментариях. Вы используете массив и "вырезаете" из него значение, но вырезанием, честно говоря, это назвать нельзя. Так как вы вместо него подставляете оставшиеся элементы массива, но от этого его размер не изменяется, он как состоял из `n` элементов, так и состоит.